# Crear y leer archivo binario de una estructura anidada

Tags: c, archivo, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy estudiando grabar en un archivo binario con `fwrite` y leerlo con `fread`.

Lo consigo hacer sin problemas con una estructura simple, pero el problema es que tengo una estructura anidada de esta manera:

```
typedef struct
{
    char fecha[11];
    float notaParcial;
}Parcial;

typedef struct
{
    char nomAsignatura[60];
    int codAsignatura;
    float notaAsignatura;
    int numParciales;
    Parcial *parciales;
}Asig;


typedef struct
{
    char nombre[100];
    char expediente[20];
    int numAsig;
    Asig *asignaturas;
}Alumnos;
```

Para ello tengo una función como la siguiente:

```
void procesar(void *datos)
{
    Alumnos *A = (Alumnos*)datos;
    int tam_alumnos = sizeof(Alumnos);
    int tam_Asig = sizeof(Asig);
    int tam_Parcial = sizeof(Parcial);
    int i, j;

    FILE *pf = fopen("mifichero.bin", "ab");
    if (!pf)
    {
        printf("No se ha podido crear el fichero.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Escribo los datos de Alumnos en mi archivo
    fwrite(A, tam_alumnos, 1, pf);
    fclose(pf);
    ////////////////////////////////


    //Leo estructura Alumnos
    pf = fopen("mifichero.bin", "rb");
    if (pf == NULL) printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero.\n");

    while (fread(A, tam_alumnos, 1, pf) > 0)
    {
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", A->nombre);
        printf("Exp: %s\n", A->expediente);
        printf("Num asig: %d\n", A->numAsig);
    }
    fclose(pf);
    ////////////////////////////////

    pf = fopen("mifichero.bin", "rb");
    if (pf == NULL) printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero.\n");

    //Leo estructura Asig
    while (fread(A, tam_Asig, 1, pf) > 0)
    {
        printf("Nombre de asignatura: %s \n", A->asignaturas->nomAsignatura);
        printf("Codigo de asignatura: %d \n", A->asignaturas->codAsignatura);
        printf("Nota de asignatura: %g \n", A->asignaturas->notaAsignatura);
        printf("Numero de parciales: %d \n", A->asignaturas->numParciales);
    }
    fclose(pf);


    pf = fopen("mifichero.bin", "rb");
    if (pf == NULL) printf("No se ha podido abrir el fichero.\n");

    //Leo estructura Parcial
    while (fread(A, tam_Parcial, 1, pf) > 0)
    {
        printf("Fecha de Parcial: %s \n", A->asignaturas->parciales->fecha);
        printf("Nota de Parcial: %g \n", A->asignaturas->parciales->notaParcial);
    }
    fclose(pf);
    ////////////////////////////////
```

Con este código tengo me imprime:

```
Nombre: Ruben
Exp: ERGO
Num asig: 1
Nombre de asignatura: ONDAS
Codigo de asignatura: 123
Nota de asignatura: 10
Numero de parciales: 1
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
Fecha de Parcial: 2
Nota de Parcial: 10
```

No comprendo porque me repite n veces Fecha de parcial y Nota de parcial.

Por otra parte, ¿hay alguna manera de evitar repetir los fread, o debo hacerlo por cada estructura como lo estoy intentando hacer?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Dado que dices que sabes leer y escribir el archivo... ¿Por qué no pones cómo estás intentando leerlo? Así te podremos decir qué estás haciendo mal. De otra forma te estaremos haciendo los deberes y esa no es una práctica común en [es.so]

Comment: Claro, ni mucho menos pretendo que me hagan los deberes. Actualizo mi entrada.

Answer (score 1):

Te enfrentas a un problema muy común. El consenso general sobre la solución adecuada a tu problema es crear "*cabeceras*" de datos que indiquen la cantidad de datos que siguen a continuación:

```
[ cantidad de elementos: X | elemento 1 | elemento 2 | … | elemento X | cantidad de elementos: Y | elemento 1 | … | elemento Y ]
```

En tu caso, tienes tres estructuras, y dos de ellas tienen colecciones de estructuras, por suerte ya guardas la cantidad de elementos en la estructura, por lo que parte la solución la tienes implementada.

#### Propuesta.

Yo crearía funciones para escribir y leer datos individualmente:

```
void escribir(Alumnos *a, FILE *f) {
    // Escribir datos de 'a'
    …

    // Guardamos la cantidad de asignaturas
    fwrite(&a->numAsig, sizeof(a->numAsig), 1, f);
    // Guardamos las asignaturas.
    for (int indice = 0, total = a->numAsig; indice != total; ++indice) {
        escribir(&a->asignaturas[indice], f);
    }
}

void escribir(Asig *a, FILE *f) {
    // Escribir datos de 'a'
    …

    // Guardamos la cantidad de parciales
    fwrite(&a->numParciales, sizeof(a->numParciales), 1, f);
    // Guardamos los parciales.
    for (int indice = 0, total = a->numParciales; indice != total; ++indice) {
        escribir(&a->parciales[indice], f);
    }
}

void escribir(Parcial *p, FILE *f) {
    // Escribir datos de 'p'
    …
}
```

```
void leer(Alumnos *a, FILE *f) {
    // Leer datos de 'a'
    …

    // Leemos la cantidad de asignaturas
    fread(&a->numAsig, sizeof(a->numAsig), 1, f);
    // Leemos cada asignatura.
    a->asignaturas = (Asig *)malloc(sizeof(Asig) * a->numAsig);
    for (int indice = 0, total = a->numAsig; indice != total; ++indice) {
        leer(&a->asignaturas[indice], f);
    }
}

void leer(Asig *a, FILE *f) {
    // Leer datos de 'a'
    …

    // Leemos la cantidad de parciales
    fread(&a->numParciales, sizeof(a->numParciales), 1, f);
    // Leemos cada parcial.
    a->parciales = (Parcial *)malloc(sizeof(Parcial) * a->numParciales);
    for (int indice = 0, total = a->numParciales; indice != total; ++índice) {
        leer(&a->parciales[indice], f);
    }
}

void leer(Parcial *p, FILE *f) {
    // Leer datos de 'p'
    …
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, la verdad es que me queda claro la idea que plantea usted para hacerlo. Sin embargo me piden realizar lo dicho desde la función "procesar". Que recibe los datos de un árbol binario con las estructuras.
¿Me podría decir cuál sería mi problema en mi código? ¿Por qué se me imprime más de la cuenta?

Comment: No veo que mi propuesta sea incompatible con hacer la tarea desde la función `procesar`: llama a la función `leer(Parcial *)` o `escribir(Parcial *)` desde allí.

Comment: Obtengo problemas con los punteros cuando se hace la llamada recursiva.

Comment: ¿Qué llamada recursiva?

Comment: Cuando llamas a la función dentro de sí misma:

`void escribir(Alumnos *a, FILE *f)`

En este caso,¿no se escribe las distintas asignaturas? Solo haces fwrite del número de asignaturas.

PD: Perdón por la tardanza.